# How to directly embed string in D3 format code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to embed a string using d3 format code directly.  Is there such a format code that exists? For reference, I am trying to format "0.0123" to "123 bps".  Any help on extracting 123 from 0.0123 also would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried percentage formats but that only multiplies by 100, and am unsure of how to multiply by a custom factor.

https://github.com/d3/d3-format

Answer (score 1):

Could you just make your own formatter for this?

```js
const formatter = n => `${n*10000} bps`;
const output = formatter(0.0123);

console.log(output); // '123 bps'
```

Comment: I am restricted to doing so via just D3 formatting as it is applied to a delta calculation made by Plotly, which only supports a valueformat.

https://plotly.com/python/indicator/

Comment: Can't you just multiply the `value` and the `delta.reference` by 10000?

Comment: That would cause the ticks to then be increased by the same factor, not sure how to remove precision via d3.  I.e. turning 10000% to 100% or 10%